# Why would this upsert fail with a duplicate id exception?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This one keep cropping up from time to time. I have the operation done as an upsert, but every so often, the service crashes because it runs into this error and I don't understand how it's even possible. I try to do the upsert using the SurveyId as the key on which to match:

```
await _surveyRepository.DatabaseCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    Builders<SurveyData>.Filter.Eq(survey => survey.SurveyId, surveyData.SurveyId),
    Builders<SurveyData>.Update
        .Set(survey => survey.SurveyLink, surveyData.SurveyLink)
        .Set(survey => survey.ClientId, surveyData.ClientId)
        .Set(survey => survey.CustomerFirstName, surveyData.CustomerFirstName)
        .Set(survey => survey.CustomerLastName, surveyData.CustomerLastName)
        .Set(survey => survey.SurveyGenerationDateUtc, surveyData.SurveyGenerationDateUtc)
        .Set(survey => survey.PortalUserId, surveyData.PortalUserId)
        .Set(survey => survey.PortalUserFirst, surveyData.PortalUserFirst)
        .Set(survey => survey.PortalUserLast, surveyData.PortalUserLast)
        .Set(survey => survey.Tags, surveyData.Tags),
    new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true })
.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And I'll occasionally get this error:

> Message: A write operation resulted in an error.   E11000 duplicate
>   key error collection: surveys.surveys index: SurveyId dup key: { :
>   "" }

The id is a string representation of a Guid and is set to unique in mongo.

So why would this happen? It is my understanding that if it finds the key, it'll update the defined properties, and if not, it'll insert. Is that not correct? Because, that is the effect that I need.

C# driver version is 2.4.1.18

Answer (score 1):

This happens because according to this [Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322):

> During an update with upsert:true option, two (or more) threads may attempt an upsert operation using the same query predicate and, upon not finding a match, the threads will attempt to insert a new document. Both inserts will (and should) succeed, unless the second causes a unique constraint violation.

Answer (score -1):

> It is my understanding that if it finds the key, it'll update the
>   defined properties, and if not, it'll insert. Is that not correct

Yes that's what upsert does. And newly inserted document will contain all fields from *criteria* part(in your case surveyId) as well as *update modification* part(all other specified fields) of your update query.

You need to set upsert=false in your query. Then it will only update documents with matching criteria, and update will fail if no match is found.

Comment: That is not the intended effect. That would simply be an update; I need an upsert. It should update the record with the specified data if the id is found and insert a new one with the provided fields if it is not found. It should never fail.